# Could a slow graphics card affect Windows's performance?

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance, graphics-card

Could a slow graphics card cause slow performance in Windows? Obviously a graphics card is mostly used when playing video games, but do Windows and normal office apps (e.g. Microsoft Office, Internet Explorer, email programs, etc) experience any benefits from having a fast card?

For example, the [Dell Inspirion 546](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/uk/en/ukbsdt1/servicetag/929RJ4J) seems to come with a reasonably fast CPU and 3GB of RAM but a very slow graphics card (the Radeon HD 3200), which also shares 256MB of system RAM. Could this cause slow downs in non-3D based applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 7/Vista, just at the desktop, if you have [Aero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero) enabled, then yes.
If the UI seems slow, try [disabling](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-aero-on-windows-vista/) it.
Aero has 3D effects and will be accelerated by the GPU.

I would actually run the System Score and see what it is. That should give you a good idea of what the bottleneck is.

Comment: Do you mean the Windows system score, or some other software?

Comment: If you mean Windows score, then everything is 5.8 or higher apart from Windows Aero performance, which is 3.6.

Comment: Yeah, that would indicate a graphics bottleneck. If Aero is enabled I would try running Windows with it off. However, I'd venture that the system will still be sluggish. Is this a fresh install and it's sluggish?

Comment: More or less. It's a cleaned up Dell Windows image. Not great, but I've pretty much removed everything extraneous.

Comment: Update: We upgraded the graphics card and everything runs a lots smoother now!